# Is Queen Elizabeth II a national of each of the Commonwealth realms?

Tags: monarchy, commonwealth

This is a follow-up to a recently asked question: [Is the monarch of the Commonwealth Realms a citizen of any or all of them?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/4472/is-the-monarch-of-the-commonwealth-realms-a-citizen-of-any-or-all-of-them)

The words "citizen" and "national" are sometimes used interchangeably, but are not quite synonyms.

It seems to me that it's rather difficult to argue that the Queen does not possess British nationality, but I am less sure about the other Commonwealth realms.

Comment: The standard reply to this sort of question is "who's asking?".

Comment: The answer is actually quite metaphysical but please bear with me. She is not a "citizen" or "national" of any State, because she IS the State itself. The Queen cannot be a citizen of her own country just as you cannot be a "person" and a "cell" within your own body at the same time. Case in point, she cannot vote in her own country because the government runs in her name.

Answer (score 5):

The question is almost meaningless.

As a British National, one has the right to live in Britain.

Does the Queen have the *right* to live in Britain? She only enjoys this privilege as long as the Government choose to allow it. There are lots of examples of Kings and Queens being deposed and subsequently exiled. It seems reasonably clear that while normal Britons enjoy the protection of the Queen's law, the Queen doesn't have these benefits as a right, but rather can remain in Britain while there is nobody strong enough to depose her.

In fact the whole notion of "rights before the law" breaks down when you have an individual person who embodies the power of the state.

This makes questions of the form "is the Queen a Canadian National" fundamentally meaningless.  No situation could arise in which the queen could seek to exercise her potential Canadian Nationality (as distinct from her Canadian suzerainty) in which there had not been a major constitutional upheaval and her status as Queen had fundamentally altered.

Comment: But ... when the Queen flies to Canada or Australia, does she need to take her passport?

Comment: This is a different question. It has been discussed elsewhere. The Queen doesn't have or need a passport. Other royals do.